# Strikethrough a list item in react todo list

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to create a to-do list app with a timestamp and strike-through the list item when the delete button is clicked, but when I click the delete button all the items get stricked-through.
I have looked everywhere but I cant get it to work for my code. I am able to extract unique id through delete button function but i cant understand how to use that id to strike only that id.

````
import "../App.css";
import moment from "moment";

const List = () => {
  const [strike, setStrike] = useState(false);
  const [addtime, setaddTime] = useState(moment().utcOffset("+05:30").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ").toString());
  const [store, setStore] = useState([]);
  const [endTime, setendTime] = useState();
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState('');
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  //to add an item

  const addItem = () => {
    if (!inputData) {
    } else {
      const allInputData = {id: new Date().getTime().toString(), name:inputData}
      setItems([...items, allInputData]);
      setInputData("");
      setaddTime(
        moment().utcOffset("+05:30").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ").toString()
      );
      setStore([...store, addtime]);
    }
  };

  // to delete an item

  const deleteItem = (index) => {
    const boolstrike = items.filter((elem) => {
      return index == elem.id;
      

    })
    
    console.log(boolstrike);
   
    setStrike(!!boolstrike);
   
  };
   //to remove time
   const deleteTime = () => {
    setendTime (moment().utcOffset("+05:30").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ").toString());

    }
   

  // to remove all items

  const removeAll = () => {
    setItems([]);
    setStore([]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="parent-div">
        <div className="child-div">
          <h3>TO DO LIST</h3>
          <div className="addItems">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="what needs to be done?"
              value={inputData}
              onChange={(e) => setInputData(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={addItem}
              className="btn btn-secondary"
            >
              Create
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="left" className="showItems">
              {items.map((elem) => {
                return (
                  <div className="eachItem" key={elem.id}>
                    <h3
                      style={{
                        textDecoration: strike ? "line-through" : "none",
                      }}
                    >
                      {elem.name}
                    </h3>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => deleteItem(elem.id)}
                      className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                   
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
            <div id="right">
              {store.map((elim, ind) => {
                return (
                  <div className="eachdate" key={ind}>
                    <h6>{"Task Created at:" + elim} </h6>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => deleteTime()}
                      className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                    
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="showItems">
            <button onClick={removeAll} className="btn btn-danger">
              Delete All
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default List;```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add strike in the items obj and track that. in that way, if delete btn is clicked, you can mark that item as strikedout.

You can set `strike` while delete

```
  const deleteItem = (index) => {
    const updatedItems = items.filter((elem) => {
      if (index == elem.id) {
        elem.strike = true;
      }
      return elem;
    });

    setItems(updatedItems);
  };
```

and based on this property class will be applied, only deleted items will strick out.

updated code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import moment from 'moment';

const List = () => {
  const [strike, setStrike] = useState(false);
  const [addtime, setaddTime] = useState(
    moment().utcOffset('+05:30').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ').toString()
  );
  const [store, setStore] = useState([]);
  const [endTime, setendTime] = useState();
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState('');
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  //to add an item

  const addItem = () => {
    if (!inputData) {
    } else {
      const allInputData = {
        id: new Date().getTime().toString(),
        name: inputData,
      };
      setItems([...items, allInputData]);
      setInputData('');
      setaddTime(
        moment().utcOffset('+05:30').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ').toString()
      );
      setStore([...store, addtime]);
    }
  };

  // to delete an item

  const deleteItem = (index) => {
    const updatedItems = items.filter((elem) => {
      if (index == elem.id) {
        elem.strike = true;
      }
      return elem;
    });

    setItems(updatedItems);
  };
  //to remove time
  const deleteTime = () => {
    setendTime(
      moment().utcOffset('+05:30').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ').toString()
    );
  };

  // to remove all items

  const removeAll = () => {
    setItems([]);
    setStore([]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="parent-div">
        <div className="child-div">
          <h3>TO DO LIST</h3>
          <div className="addItems">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="what needs to be done?"
              value={inputData}
              onChange={(e) => setInputData(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={addItem}
              className="btn btn-secondary"
            >
              Create
            </button>
          </div>
          <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="left" className="showItems">
              {items.map((elem) => {
                console.log(elem);
                return (
                  <div className="eachItem" key={elem.id}>
                    <h3
                      style={{
                        textDecoration: elem.strike ? 'line-through' : 'none',
                      }}
                    >
                      {elem.name}
                    </h3>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => deleteItem(elem.id)}
                      className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
            <div id="right">
              {store.map((elim, ind) => {
                return (
                  <div className="eachdate" key={ind}>
                    <h6>{'Task Created at:' + elim} </h6>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => deleteTime()}
                      className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="showItems">
            <button onClick={removeAll} className="btn btn-danger">
              Delete All
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default List;
```